# Calculate number of students per class without using a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to run this query on MySQL workbench if I removed the GROUP BY condition it outputs the table of the data with the total number of students in all classes. I need the total per class WITHOUT USING JOIN AS THIS IS TRAINING ON SUBQUERY

```
SELECT Class.ID,Class.Name,Class.Description,Class.Code,Class.MaximumStudents,
 (SELECT COUNT(StudentID) AS numberOfStudentinClass 
  FROM ClassStudent 
  GROUP BY CLASSID) AS NumberOFStudentPerClass 
FROM Class;
```

Here is the screenshot of the query and the result

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this , without using `GROUP BY`.

```
select class.name ,
       (select count(student.id) as total 
        from student
        where class.id = student.class_id
       ) as custom 
from class;
```

Comment: I need this without using JOIN

Comment: select class.name, (select count(student.id) as total from student where class.id = student.class_id) as custom from class;

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without the class name, then you can simply run this...

```
Select class_id, count(*)
From classstudent
Group by 1
;
```

However, if you want the class name as well, there are only a couple of options.

1. Join to the class table on class
2. Use a correlated sub query (but this is sort of like a join but without the keyword join). You could also use the old "list of comma separated tables in the from clause" but this still involves a join, just without the join keyword.
   Or
3. Denormalise the class name by adding a table to the class student table. I do not recommend this so I will not show this SQL.

Here is option 1. I do not understand why you specifically *do not* want to do a join. After all, this is what a join is for....

Perhaps you could update your question with an explanation as to why you prefer to not use a join....

Anyway here is option 1.

```
Select class_name, count(*) as cnt
From classStudent cs join class c on
      Cs.class_id = c.class_id
Group by class_name
;
```

Comment: Isn’t it pretty obvious that this is homework and that’s why the requirements are the way they are? By the way, you missed that one of the requirements is to use a sub query

Comment: Nope, i totally did not see that until you mentioned it @JoakimDanielson. Probably bacause i was asked a similarly strange question at work a few days ago. I gave a similar answer - go with the flow dude, that's what joins are for - don't make life hard for yourself. I can see it now ...

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly reasonable to express this as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Name, c.Description, c.Code, c.MaximumStudents,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM ClassStudent cs
        WHERE cs.CLASSID = c.ID
       ) as NumberOFStudentPerClass 
FROM Class c;
```

Notes:

- Your version will not work.  Among other things, you will get an error that multiple rows are returned by the subquery.
- The subquery will always return exactly one row, even if no rows match.  In that case, the value will be `0`, not `NULL`.
- The condition `cs.CLASSID = c.ID` is a *correlation condition*, matching rows in the subquery to the outer query.
- Use table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.
- There is no need to name the column in the subquery.  You do want to name it in the outer query.